# The equation $f(x)= \frac{3^x+1}{2}$ for all positive integers x

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The equation $f(x)= \frac{3^x+1}{2}$ for all positive integers $x$ generates a sequence such that the difference of every consecutive f(x) forms another say g(x) such that $g(x) = 3^{x-1}$.
What I did is to find $f'(x)$ and expecting that it is equal to $3^x$, but it did not.

For example: if $x= 1,2,3,4,5$, $f(x) = 2,5,14,41,122$. I observed that $ 5-2 =3; 14-5 = 3^2;41-14=3^3 ; 122-41= 3^4  $ Is this true for all? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing, $f(x+1)-f(x)=\frac{3^{x+1}+1}{2}-\frac{3^x+1}{2}=\frac{3^{x+1}-3^{x}}{2}=3^x\frac{3-1}{2}=3^x$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, anyway.. why is the derivative of the function not applicable here?my initial approach was to find the derivative, is it wrong?

Comment: You are finding change between two points. That is, the difference between $f(x+1)$ and $f(x)$ whereas the derivative tell you the $\textit{rate of change}$ at that point.

Comment: isn't it the derivative is $$\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{1}$$? so it should be the same, right? so it must be applicable as well? am I right? thanks

Comment: no! that is not the derivative. That is the average change. Look for average change from $x$ to $y$ is $(f(y)-f(x))/(y-x)$. This depends upon two values, $x$ and $y$. Here your $y$ is equal to $x+1$. The derivative of function depends only on the point you are at. The definition is $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that answer..